# Random Forest Classification, test training data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm new in the machine learning environment. I noticed that a random forest classifier is composed of Decision trees, which rely on statistics to classify a sample. is it possible for a random forest to erroneously classify a sample who was in his training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
If depth of Decision trees is not big enough to capture the essence of the data.
For example lets consider data with two features `X1` and `X2`.

```
target = 1 if X1 >5 and X2 > 10, else target = 0
```

With depth one, decision tree will have to rely only on one of the features.

For example sample if decision tree use `X1` feature to construct the split,
both samples `(7, 15)` and `(7, 7)` will be classified as 1, which is wrong for `(7,7)`, because `X2 = 7 < 10`.